# On dd utility detail

Tags: dd, copy

Apologize if it'd be too meticulous getting to know few Linux works but cant help

How is `dd` utility copying in some HW / SW condition at least here, copied 3.5 GB onto Usb disk with OS give freed 7 GB memory, its process speed decreases by a significant amount from

start ~70 MB/s to ~ 41 MB/s in a minute
then to ~27 MB/s in another minute till to ~13.7 MB/s after 4 minutes from start to the end ~6 min

how can we set or beef it up to do all more efficiently to drop just by slight number ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transfer "freezes" when writing big files on USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/734827/transfer-freezes-when-writing-big-files-on-usb-drive)

Comment: Also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/397249/system-freezes-unresponsive-unusable-when-copying-large-file-to-usb?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I converted an internal M.2 SSD to USB3 M.2 adapter. That is almost as fast as it was as an internal drive. My backups to flash drives are so slow now and so fast to external SSD. Now not planning on buying any more flash drives, but I already have many.

Comment: The latest models of external SSDs are very fast and convenient.

Answer (score 1):

The latest models of external SSDs are very fast and convenient. Using an external SSD is a good solution to this type of problem because they have also become very affordable.